# Wiki engine to embed extensive Tex and PGF/Tikz code

Tags: tikz-pgf, rendering, latex2html, wiki

I would like to create a wiki (several authors) with scientific content, including text, equations, graphs and schemes.

I wish to use LaTeX macros (including my own ones) and draw graphics with the powerful PGF/Tikz syntax. My aim is to minimize the work to turn a `.tex` file into a wiki page, and to keep code flexibility (ideal case would be to copy/paste raw `.tex` file content in a wiki page and the server should render it).

Is [Mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.or) able to do that?

Is it possible to approach similar behavior with `latex2html`?

Any feedback would be welcome! Thanks